Number of $F_p$-matrices ac=ca, bd = db , ad - da = cb - bc is polynomial in p ? ("Manin matrix variety" - normal ? Cohen–Macaulay ? )
Consider four $n\times n$ matrices $a,b,c,d$  over finite field $F_q$ (or $F_p$ for simplicity), such that they satisfy three equations: $ac=ca,bd=db, ad-da=cb-bc $. Thus an affine algebraic manifold is defined ("Manin matrix variety").
Question 1: Is it true that number of such matrices over $F_q$ is polynomial in $q$ ? (I.e. the  variety is "polynomial count" - which is quite rare phenomena for algebraic manifolds).
Question 1b: If yes - can nice generating function  be produced similar to "commuting variety" ?
Question 2: Additionally we may ask if variety is: irreducible, normal and Cohen-Macaulay ? Similar to results/expectations about its "younger brother" - the "commuting variety" - just: $ac=ca$.
Computational experiments:

For $2 \times 2$ matrices computations suggest the following polynomial: $ p^7 ( p^4+2p^3-p-1) $, checked for p=2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19.
For $3 \times 3$ we only computed number for p=2: 6078976

Variations - similar to known results for commuting variety we can restrict blocks $a,b,c,d$ to be invertible, nilpotent, (anti)-symmetric, triangular, etc. and still expect the polynomial count property:

Invertibility. Additional constraint $a,b,c,d$ are invertible - polynom fit for 2x2 and $p=2,3,5,7$ -  is: $p(p+1)(p−1)^4(p^5+p^4−3p^3+4p^2−6p+4)$ (verified by fast code of Peter Taylor based on Grobner basis. PS I had some doubts about it is polynomial - but resolved now - thanks to Peter).

Nilpotency. With additional constraint 2-niltpotency: $0=a^2=b^2=c^2=d^2$ : 2x2 case checked for (p=2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19) : $2p^5+p^4-2p^3$, 3x3 case checked for p=2,3,5: $4p^{10}+5p^9+p^8-6p^7-6p^6-p^5+2p^4+2p^3$ . For 3x3 case with just nilpotency: $2p^{13}+p^{12}+2p^{10}+3p^9+3p^8+p^6+p^5$

(ANTIsymmetric): 2x2 $p^4$ (obviously), 3x3 :  $p^7+2p^6-p^4-p^3$ checked for p=2,3,5,7,11 .

Symmetric: 2x2 $2p^9+p^8-2p^7$ (checked p=2,3,5,7,11,13,17), 3x3: $4p^{15} + 2p^{14}− 3p^{13}−p^{12}− 2p^{11}+p^{9}$ checked for p=2,3,5.

Upper triangular with zero diagonal: 2x2 $p^4$ obviously, $2p^9+p^8−2p^7$ (same as  2x2 block upper-triangular matrices - probably due to standard isomorphism ) .

Uppertriangular: 2x2 $2p^9+p^8−2p^7$ (same as above for antisymmetric 3x3). Suspicious: $10p^{15}-4p^{14}+2p^{13}-2p^{12}-19p^{11}-p^{10}-p^9$ - coefficients are big, fit changes from p=2,3 to p=2,3,5, some other bad signs. So there are doubts that it is polynomial count variety.

Uppertriangular and squared to zero (a la A.A.Kirillov  - see references below) 3x3 case - $2p^8+2p^7−2p^6−2p^5+p^4$ - checked p=2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19. (2x2 case: $p^4$ obviously).


Motivation: Manin matrices are beautiful object which satisfies many interesting properties and have various applications in representation theory, knot theory, etc, so general (exaggerated) expectation - whatever reasonable property we propose it will be true for Manin matrices (see example of Koszulity here (thanks to Steven Sam). In particular -  it is a natural generalization of the "commuting variety" - so motivation for the questions - whether the properties known/expected for the "commuting variety" generalize to "Manin matrix variety" ?
Thanks/Related MO/MSE questions/papers:

The polynomials above were computed with the help of Peter Taylor code appeared in the mathoverflow answer on related question - code is very fast and efficient - allowing to guess polynom just by values at few points. There were other ways proposed - thanks to all (Peter Taylor, Roland Bacher, Max Alekseyev)  who shared ideas !

Here Will Sawin, Ycor, David E Speyer, Anton Mellit  shared approaches to tackle more simple case $AB+BA=0$, it might be some ideas in particular from Sawin's answer (which is the most general) might be used for the present question.

Here David E Speyer, Olivier Schiffmann provided very insightful answers on related more simple question - counting nilpotent commuting matrices and references to "Motivic Donaldson-Thomas invariants and McKay correspondence", "On the number of points of the Lusztig nilpotent variety over a finite field" context of these questions.

The question on generating function might be related to the so-called "exponential formulas" which is beautifully exposed in  Qiaochu Yuan blog, see also q-analogue (thanks to Ofir Gorodetsky), $F_1$-analogue (thanks to Gjergji Zaimi),   $e^{cycle} = permutation$.

Some remarkable materials on $F_q$ counting problems: Steven Sam "Counting matrices over finite fields"  https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~ssam/talks/2011/finitefield.pdf,
Yifeng Huang "Generating function from counting mutually annihilating matrices and alike" https://yifeng-huang-math.github.io/files/talk_gocc.pdf

In 90-ies A.A.Kirillov was interested (1, 2,3)   in count of unitriangular matrices $X^2=0$ motivated by the extension of his famous orbit method in representation theory to finite nilpotent groups of unitriangular matrices. He found connections of these counting polynomials to q-Hermite polynomials, Euler-Bernoulli numbers etc. Some his question was resolved by D.Zeilberger.

Various activity about "polynomial count variety" questions was motivated in part by M.Kontsevich conjecture disproved in "Matroids, motives and conjecture of Kontsevich".

Some more references here. (If you know more - please add).


Generalizations: The question above appeals to $2\times 2$ Manin matrices, it is natural to expect similar polynomial count phenomena for $n\times m$ Manin matrices (but not normality - because normality break for n-tuples of commuting matrices). One can also consider super-and-q-analogues of Manin matrices and cases $M(u)$-polynomial Manin matrices (which produce relations like here). As well as some generalizations to some other quadratics algebras (and their B,C,D versions due to A.Molev).
PS
The questions above arise quite years ago in our paper, but I am not aware of any progress.

Very interesting question. I tried to think in terms of my techniques and organization in https://yifeng-huang-math.github.io/files/paper_comm_endo.pdf but I don't think I have an answer yet. It would be somewhat surprising if the invertible count does turn out to be not polynomial while the usual count and the nilpotent count are. There might be a hope for 2x2 and 3x3 matrices since commuting pairs should be in principle classifiable (suggested by the fact that commuting triple count is doable for up to 3x3).

@PeterTaylor Thanks for the remark and thanks again for the code you provided before. I am not quite familiar with SAGE - but looking on the code - does it perform remainder modula  2  ?  (We work over F_2 = Z/2 )

@PeterTaylor only those do not make mistake - who do nothing )))  If you would have some time - would be possible to check the case of "each block invertible matrices"  with SAGE ?  I have some doubts that my pytorch code is correct in that case , because not very careful with float / int conversion in my code.

My initial thought was that it should be easy to extend the 3x3 a bit further, but I'm finding the code slower to execute than I expected. Maybe I can leave it running on the invertible $a,b,c,d$ case for a few days and see how far it gets.

@PeterTaylor I think it is possible to extend 3x3, but for the price of some math. Since relations are GL(N) conjugation invariant - we can first reduce "a" to normal form - Frobenius normal form - works for F_p also.  And then calculate for each representative of "a"  the number solution and multiply it by size of GL/Stab and sum over all. That would reduce computations. But it requires some work.  Also it breaks symmetry m[0,0]=0 which I am using...

I confirm your values for $p=2,3,5$, working on $p=7$. The guessed polynomial doesn't look so bad when you factor it as $p (p + 1) (p - 1)^4 (p^5 + p^4 - 3p^3 + 4p^2 - 6p + 4)$.

@PeterTaylor Wow ! Thanks !  That is cool ! And now I see a small bug, in auxiliary part of my code - I checked divisibility by (p-1)^3 and get negative - but now I see there is typing error in that line. That was one of the reason for my doubts. Now we see divisibility by (p-1)^4 -and that is good sign  ! PS the case p=7 took about 4 hours for my code. (Happy to use Kaggle (belongs to Google) cloud and that it is for free ) .

$p=7$ literally just completed and checks out.

@PeterTaylor how did you manage to do it so fast ? my code runs 4 hours for p=7 (one CPU kernel on Kaggle free cloud). PS I tried GPU, but my code is not good for it - only slows down the main part.

Groebner bases. Code

@YifengHuang Thanks for the comments and your works are truly remarkable ! Concerning invertible matrices cases - my doubts are resolved now with the help of Peter Taylor. So I think it is polynomial. Yes, I also think that some cases can be classified. Also seems to me cases with conditions X^2=0 might be most simples ones. PS I also added checks on (anti)-symmetric/triangular cases.

Now the case of triangular matrix counts bothers me - not sure it is polynomial count.

Thanks for the updated checks! In terms of upper triangularity, a possible other thing to do for 3x3 is block-upper-triangular with block sizes 1+2 (also 2+1, but the problem is isomorphic). At the end one could hope (or dream...) for a nice 2-variable generating function for blocks n_1+n_2, since it has an interpretation as 2-step flag of representations. So 1+2 could be a problem easier than 1+1+1, as 1+1+1 belongs to a 3-variable generating function for blocks n_1+n_2+n_3.

Good news: for $p=11$ I get $227199720000$, so the guessed polynomial holds up.

@PeterTaylor WOW ! How  ? )

Same program running for 183 hours.

This works for q=4 too, using Peter Taylor code adapted to work over GF(q). The number is 1833840.

@F.C. Wow !!!!!
